# Robot Framework and Django

Tags: python, django, testing, robotframework

I am trying to use Robot Framework to acceptance testing my django app.

The thing is, that to test my django app I need to call

```
./manage.py runserver
```

To start the server. Can I make Robot Framework to do it for me? And stop it after the tests of course.

Or, even better, it is possible to make that the tests suites runs under the django LiveServerTestCase?

Comment: I am using OSX Yosemite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robot has a library named [Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) which is specifically designed for starting and stopping processes. You can use the [Start Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Start%20Process) and [Terminate Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Terminate%20Process) keywords to start and stop the webserver via a [suite setup and suite teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown). It would look something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Process
| Suite Setup | Start the webserver
| Suite Teardown | Stop the webdserver

*** Keywords ***
| Start the webserver
| | ${django process}= | Start process | python | manage.py
| | Set suite variable | ${django process}

| Stop the webserver
| | Terminate Process | ${django process}
```

Of course, you'll want to add some bullet proofing such as making sure the process actually starts, and possibly catching errors if it doesn't exit cleanly. You will also probably need to give an explicit path to manage.py, but hopefully this gives the general idea.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://github.com/kitconcept/robotframework-djangolibrary which seems to handle exactly this.

> Or, even better, it is possible to make that the tests suites runs under the Django LiveServerTestCase?

This is a much more interesting approach as we could then mix robot tests with other tests. I'll post here if I figure out how to do it.

Comment: While it may have been very relevant back in time, nowaday I see two problems with this solution :

First :
> DjangoLibrary is currently tested against Django 1.8.x, 1.9.x, 1.11.x with SQLite and Postgres on Python 2.7 and 3.6.

It won't be relevant for all versions.

Second :
And according to the project page, the last build errored and hasn't been updated since april 2019.